# Cycling through DropDownItems in ToolStripSplitButton

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm app and on it I have a `ToolStripSplitButton` that contains three item (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3).

Now what I would like to do is to allow the user to click on the `ToolStripSplit` button and then assign the next value to the the `ToolStripSplit` button's Text Property. I have come up with the following solution which works fine but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this:

```
private void toolStripSplitButton_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripSplitButton tsb = (ToolStripSplitButton)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < tsb.DropDownItems.Count; i++)
    {
        int ii = i + 1;
        if (ii >= tsb.DropDownItems.Count)
        {
            ii = 0;
        }

        if (tsb.Text == tsb.DropDownItems[i].Text)
        {
            tsb.Text = tsb.DropDownItems[ii].Text;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is in the eye of the beholder.  My version:

```
private void toolStripSplitButton1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ToolStripSplitButton tsb = (ToolStripSplitButton)sender;
  string text = tsb.DropDownItems[0].Text;
  bool found = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < tsb.DropDownItems.Count; i++) {
    if (found) text = tsb.DropDownItems[i].Text;
    found = (tsb.Text == tsb.DropDownItems[i].Text);
  }
  tsb.Text = text;
}
```